# App not loading data with WiFi connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-internet, android-data-usage

Many of the app users are complaining on playstore recently that our app is not working with Wi-Fi, and works perfectly with cellular data. As a developer I tried with few devices and different Wi-Fi connections and the app works completely fine, I was curious if anybody faced similar kind of issue.
The app code do not differentiate if the device is connected to wifi or cellular data. I have checked these [links](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyNote8/comments/7tgyeg/some_apps_are_not_working_properly_when_connected/) but couldn't get any clue as why some users cannot get the app working with Wi-Fi connection.